# Get different values of same string in PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have checkboxes of categories in a form. When checkbox is changed, from is submitted through ajax and get the values in PHP.

//form

```
foreach($somethings and $something){
    <input class="input_sale_category" type="checkbox" name="category" value="something->value" />`
}
```

I get the form data and submit through ajax

```
      $('.input_sale_category').click(function() {
        var formData = $('#filter_sale_form').serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: myurl,
          data: formData
          
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
          }
        });
      });
```

In PHP, I am getting input fields as a string

```
category=nexus-chair-offer&category=office-desks&category=office-storage
```

I tried to get the inputs values of `category` using `explode`, `parse_str` but could not get all the values of `category`

```
parse_str($str, $output);

var_dump($output);
```

How can I achieve this? Regex seems an option, but I not good at regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string)

Comment: if you want it on array form, use `name="category[]"` and then just access it like any normal `$_GET` request in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in you html code,
You are using same 'name' property in all of you input tag
What this will do is only sand 1 value to backend.

change you input tag like this

```
foreach($somethings and $something){
<input class="input_sale_category" type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="something->value" />`
}
```

check this answer as well, it might help,
[Get checkbox values using checkbox name using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192522/get-checkbox-values-using-checkbox-name-using-jquery)

You can also get values manually and pass it in ajax request's data

```
var checkboxes_value = []; 
   $('.input_sale_category').each(function(){  
        //if($(this).is(":checked")) { 
        if(this.checked) {              
             checkboxes_value.push($(this).val());                                                                               
        }  
   }); 
//checkboxes_value will be array of checked checkboxes
```

Comment: I already checked by changing the name to array but, ajax submit the same string.

Comment: @VijayRana Can you console fromData and paste it here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52441012/how-to-access-and-pass-checkbox-values-to-ajax
i also found similar solution here.

Comment: Form data is submitted like this `sale_category=725&sale_category=96&sale_category=91`

Comment: I am getting the checkbox values

Comment: @VijayRana Issue here is that you are getting key values pairs but keys should be unique and you have same key 3 times, so php will take only one value.

Comment: if you are getting the check box values as array just send that array in request data and you will get your data in php.